# Swift: Trying to rotate a drawn shape?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, core-graphics, core-animation

I'm having trouble trying to rotate the shape I have drawn in the following code: I tried using:

```
triangle.transform = triangle.transform.rotated(by: 3.14159)
```

but that gives me an error of "value of type 'CATransform3D' has no member 'rotated'". I'm not sure how to rotate the shape.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
    trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5))
    trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5) + 100, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5) - 50))
    trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5) + 100, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5) + 50))
    trianglePath.close()

    let triangle = CAShapeLayer()
    triangle.path = trianglePath.cgPath
    triangle.fillColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(triangle)
}
```

Comment: **Hint:** It makes sense that a **3D** transform doesn't support rotation around an **unspecified** axis :-)

Comment: @NicolasMiari I thought the transform I'm using was 2D? Should i be using CATransform3DMakeRotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to rotate your triangle, you can use use `CGAffineTransform`

```
 triangle.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi))
```

or using `CATransform3D`, rotating in Z axis by pi

```
 triangle.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 0, 0, 1)
```

but to this work you need to adjust also your `CAShapeLayer` frame

```
 triangle.frame = self.view.bounds //this do the trick
```

For animate after it shows

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) { 
          triangle.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)) //this 
          triangle.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 0, 0, 1) //or this
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: gives me error: "Cannot assign value of type 'CGAffineTransform' to type 'CGTransform3D'"

Comment: @diet7up sorry i don't see that your triangle is a shapeLayer i will update my answer properly

Comment: @Reiner so does this rotate the entire layer? or just the triangle? because when use this code, the shape disappears

Comment: @diet7up check my answer again was edited, the problem is the frame of your `CAShapeLayer`

Comment: thanks it worked for me :) when i put it in an animation though it just loads rotated, how would i make it so that it rotates after loading?

Comment: @diet7up updated my answer with the animation let me know if works